# JFilechooser "Look In" Drop down Does Not Appear on Frame GlassPane

Tags: java, swing, drop-down-menu, jfilechooser, glasspane

So I have been having some problems with the JFilechooser in my swing app, and my troubleshooting hasn't been getting me anywhere.

I have be able to embed the file chooser into a panel inside my application.

the problem is the drop-down button to select other directories and locations on Windows is not enabled, and so is the "File Type" drop down.

[image: Clicking on either of the drop down buttons does nothing]

Thanks for your time guys!

EDIT 1: So i've done additional testing and it seems that putting a filechooser on the JFrame GlassPane causes the Drop down to not appear, possibly because it is "behind" the glassPane or the Filebrowser... not sure how to fix this still, hopefully this helps narrow down the solution.

Edit2: 
Here is some UI code to reproduce the bug:

```
  public void gui(){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    frame.setSize(800, 800);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    //Containment Panel
    RightBottomCenter = new JPanel();


     //Setup Glass Pane
    JPanel glass = (JPanel) frame.getGlassPane();
    glass.setVisible(true);

    //Config Filechooser
    fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setDragEnabled(false);
    fc.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG);
    fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
    fc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    fc.setApproveButtonText("Select");
    fc.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight() - 100));


    RightBottomCenter.add(fc);
    glass.add(RightBottomCenter);
    frame.setVisible(true);


}
```

Still tinkering around, but haven't found an good solution yet.

Comment: *"Due to the compexity of the UI I can't show the whole configuration of the UI in which the chooser is located.."*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

[*The Glass Pane*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) tutorial includes a `GlassPaneDemo` that shows how to *forward* mouse events to the underlying components. You may be able to adapt the approach shown [there](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/GlassPaneDemoProject/src/components/GlassPaneDemo.java).